# 404 route always display with multiple BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I had created multiple BrowserRouter for separate basename but when I am trying implement 404 route it will be displayed below of each route component

```
    <BrowserRouter basename={Modules.inbox}>

    <div className="AppRouting">
        <Switch>
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.inbox} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.inbox + '/:slug'} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.settings} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.sending} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.trash} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.storage} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.blockWords} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.signature} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.defaultContent} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.rejectedMail} component={CommunicationRouting} />
            <SecretRoute exact path={CommunicationRoute.routingRules} component={CommunicationRouting} />

        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>

    <BrowserRouter basename={Modules.project} history={history} >

    <div className="AppRouting">
        <Switch>

            <SecretRoute exact path='/' component={Timesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/fill-timesheet' component={Timesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path="/(new-timesheet|serverError|open-task|thank-you|network-error)/" component={Timesheet} />
            <BlockTimesheetRoute exact path='/block-fill-timesheet' component={Mtimesheet} />
            <BlockTimesheetRoute exact path="/(block-timesheet|serverError|block-open-task|mthankyou|network-error)/" component={Mtimesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path="/project-detail" component={ProjectList} />
            <SecretRoute exact path="/my-timesheet" component={Timesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/calender' component={Dashboardcalendar} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/review-timesheet' component={ReviewApprove} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/review-timesheets' component={ReviewApprove} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/timesheets-view' component={ReviewApprove} />

        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>

<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

The last component always display with all route, I can't create one browserroute  because I had a separate base name for each module

Comment: <Route path= '*' component={NotFound} /> this will catch for the component which you didnt defined the path. But if you doesn't give * also it will work i tried it in latest version. I didnt understood why there are multiple browser routers can you explain little further in depth what you are trying to solve so it will be helpful to answer

Comment: @Dilip I have separate module for each section and we need separate url for each module like 'project/details, project/list, sales/details, sales/list' so i had create multiple browser routers. I had added 404 route in bottom of last url but it's also not working

Comment: Try using <Route path= '*' component={NotFound} /> in between each <Switch > and let me know did it worked for you ?

Comment: <Route path="*" component={NotFound} /> still same issue

Comment: i think its because of using multiple BrowserRouters, as you said its different module  i need to look further into it since this is first time i am seeing the basename. let me check and it will update

Comment: can you try to recreate the issue in codesandbox for a browser router use two or three routes, too the see the issue

Comment: check this url, I had added only two files App.js and Approuting.js. It just code not in working condition so you can identify problem

https://codesandbox.io/embed/festive-waterfall-wh8j1

Comment: i have added a work around solution, i was not able to figure from the official docs. and i seems this to be a question, i dont know the design side of the product so from a question perspective i know this solution test it, i have tested with minimal time. Anyways happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one didnt find any official docs related to this, so the problem was because each BrowserRouter is a different one, so it will execute through each at last when we define in the last BrowserRouter as 404 also it will execute with each one.

So somehow we need to have check using render we can check with the predefined routes pathnames, check this one

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const pathNames = ['/test', '/test/', '/test/inbox', '/test/inbox/', '/test/settings', '/test/settings/',
  '/sample', '/sample/', '/sample/inbox', '/sample/inbox/', '/sample/settings', '/sample/settings/'
]


const Inbox = () => <div>Inbox Component</div>;

const Settings = () => <div>Settings</div>;

const NotFound = (props) => {
  if (!pathNames.includes(props.location.pathname))
    return (
      <div>Not Found</div>
    )
  else
    return null;
}

const HomePageTest = () => <div>Home Page Test</div>

const HomePageSample = () => <div>Home Page Sample</div>



function App() {
  return (
    <>

      <BrowserRouter basename='/test'>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePageTest} />
          <Route exact path="/inbox" component={Inbox} />
          <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/sample">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePageSample} />
          <Route exact path="/inbox" component={Inbox} />
          <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='*' render={(props) => <NotFound {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define 404 route in bottom.

```
          <Switch>

            <SecretRoute exact path='/' component={Timesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/fill-timesheet' component={Timesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path="/(new-timesheet|serverError|open-task|thank-you|network-error)/" component={Timesheet} />
            <BlockTimesheetRoute exact path='/block-fill-timesheet' component={Mtimesheet} />
            <BlockTimesheetRoute exact path="/(block-timesheet|serverError|block-open-task|mthankyou|network-error)/" component={Mtimesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path="/project-detail" component={ProjectList} />
            <SecretRoute exact path="/my-timesheet" component={Timesheet} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/calender' component={Dashboardcalendar} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/review-timesheet' component={ReviewApprove} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/review-timesheets' component={ReviewApprove} />
            <SecretRoute exact path='/timesheets-view' component={ReviewApprove} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />

        </Switch>
```

Don't define 404 route seperately.

Comment: I had done this but it's still display with all route

Comment: @BahadurSinghDeol can you explain me why two browserRouter you have defined instead of one. because your all route can work inside single swtch of browserRouter.

Comment: I have separate module for each section and we need separate url for each module like 'project/details, project/list, sales/details, sales/list' so i had create multiple browser routers. I had added 404 route in bottom of last url but it's also not working

Comment: @BahadurSinghDeol can you share your code in sandbox so that i could check.

Comment: check this url, I had added only two files App.js and Approuting.js. It just code not in working condition so you can identify problem

https://codesandbox.io/embed/festive-waterfall-wh8j1